# How do I evaluate this integral: $\int_{-5}^{5}x\sqrt{1+4x^2}\,dx$?

Tags: integration

I don't know how to do this

$$\int_{-5}^{5}x\sqrt{1+4x^2}\,dx$$

I went trough my notes and saw a similar integral but I don't understand some of the steps.
The integral I saw was $$\int_{-1}^{1}x\sqrt{1+9x^2}\,dx$$ then

$$\sqrt{ {1+9x^2} }x -  \int_{-1}^{1}xd\sqrt{1+9x^2}\ = 2 \sqrt{ {10} } -\int_{-1}^{1}x\frac{9x}{\sqrt{1+9x^2}}dx
 = 2 \sqrt{ {10} } - \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{9x^2 +1-1}{\sqrt{1+9x^2}}dx 
$$ 
*Here I don't understand why we add 1 and then -1.

=
$$2 \sqrt{ {10} }-\int_{-1}^{1}\sqrt{1+9x^2}\ +\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+9x^2}}dx = ?  $$ then I don't know how it went to this with the integral after $$2 \sqrt{ {10} }$$

Comment: The substitution $u=1+4x^2$ would help regardless of the limits.

Comment: Try the substitution $u = 1+4x^2.$  Although JG's solution below is elegant.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 4):

It's $0$ because of the odd integrand.

Answer (score 1):

Use the u-substitution $u=1+4x^2$:

$$
\int_{-5}^{5}x\sqrt{1+4x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{8}\int_{101}^{101}\sqrt{u}\,du=0.
$$

That's, of course, is going to be equal to zero because the definite integral from $a$ to $a$ is defined to be zero:

$$\int_{a}^{a}f(x)\,dx=0.$$

Comment: So the integral $$\int^4_{-4}x^2\,dx$$ is zero as well? Because if I substitute $u=x^2$, then I get zero? I don't think so... Do you see that something goes wrong? And what is it?

Comment: Take a close look at the bounds. I said from $a$ to $a$. Not from $-a$ to $a$.

Comment: Yes but after I set $u=x^2$ then I get $$\int^{16}_{16} f(u) \,du $$ for some function $f$, right? And according to you it is zero.... right?

Comment: Sorry but unfortunately you don't see my point

Comment: $u=x^2$ would not be a correct u-substitution. The correct u-substitution in your case would be $u=\frac{x^3}{3}$: $$\int_{-4}^{4}x^2\,dx=\int_{-4}^{4}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^3}{3}\right)\,dx=\int_{-64/3}^{64/3}\,du=u\bigg|_{-64/3}^{64/3}=\frac{64}{3}+\frac{64}{3}=\frac{2\cdot 64}{3}=\frac{128}{3}.$$ This is the same answer as $$\int_{-4}^{4}x^2 \,dx=2\int_{0}^{4}x^2\,dx=2\frac{x^3}{3}\bigg|_{0}^{4}=2\left(\frac{64}{3}-0\right)=\frac{128}{3}.$$